# clearInterval() not working after stop button click

Tags: html, jquery

i am trying  to Refresh div using java script . setInterval() and clearInterval (), its working fine,  but i want  stop  Refresh   process  for  single div  when i clicked  stop  button ..clear Interval not working herer

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.output').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).closest('.g').attr('id');

                Go(id);

            })
            $('.bt').click(function () {
           var id = $(this).closest('.g').attr('id');
                stop(id)
            });

            function Go(id) {
                id = setInterval(function () {
                    Chat_msg('Ch04', id, u)
                }, 3000);
            };
            function stop(id) {

                clearInterval(id);

            }

        })

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="a" class='g'>
    <div class="output"></div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="stop" class="bt" />
</div>

<div id="b">
    <div class="output"></div>
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="stop"  class="bt"/>
</div>

<div id="c">
     <div class="output"></div>
    <input id="Button3" type="button" value="stop" class="bt" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is the variable returned by `setInterval` is out of scope in the handler for the `stop` button.

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable for your interval.

```
var interv = null;

interv = setInterval(function { ... }, 5000);

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    if (interv) clearInterval(intev);
})
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be global.  It just needs to be accessible to both scopes.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the reference you associated with `setInterval` is not within the scope of your stop-button handler.

```
$("#start").on("click", function(){
  var interv = setInterval(function(){ /*...*/ }, 1000);
});

$("#stop").on("click", function(){
  clearInterval(interv);
});
```

In the code above, our `interv` variable is not within the scope of our #stop button handler. We could change this by moving it up another level:

```
var interv;

$("#start").on("click", function(){
  interv = setInterval(function(){ /*...*/ }, 1000);
});

$("#stop").on("click", function(){
  clearInterval(interv);
});
```

Now both handlers have access to the `interv` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have gone about this in the past is using a function that uses a set timeout to call itself.

```
var stop = false
function caller  () {
  if (stop === true){
    //do something
    setTimeout(caller() , 1000);
  }
  else{
    //do something after button has  been click and stop is set to true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a combination of a scoping issue, and interchangeably using `id` DOM attributes with `setInterval` response values.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var timeouts = {};

        $('.output').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).closest('.g').attr('id');
            go(id);
        });

        $('.bt').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).closest('.g').attr('id');
            stop(id);
        });

        function go(id) {
            timeouts[id] = setInterval(function () {
                Chat_msg('Ch04', id, u)
            }, 3000);
        }

        function stop(id) {
            clearInterval(timeouts[id]);
        }
    });
</script>
```